# How to display difference in minute between 2 times in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

Is their any way to to calculate difference in Hours , minutes , seconds using excel function

- **start time** : `'23-DEC-19 09.00.17.393922000 AM'`
- **end time** : `'23-DEC-19 09.00.26.453921000 AM'`

I have tried this , but it does not show any result :

```
=INT(B2-A2) & " days, " & HOUR(B2-A2) & " hours, " & MINUTE(B2-A2) & " minutes and " & SECOND(B2-A2) & " seconds"
```

**Expected like this output :**

Output

[image]

It displays some like error : `#VALUE`

Comment: Are they strings or actual date/time, your formula works fine for me.

Comment: @Warcupine : No bro not working i tried its a actual date/time . I even tried to enclose within single quote

Comment: @lapin46421 how certain are you that Excel has them stored as date/time values though? to check, select the cells and try changing number format to short date or long date. If it makes no difference, they're strings. I'm guessing they're strings, and when I put them into excel they're too complex for excel to interpret as date/time values, even using `=DATEVALUE(B1)`

Comment: @SpencerBarnes : can you please help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `23-DEC-19 09.00.17.393922000 AM` is not a format that Excel can parse automatically from text to an actual time.

You will need to change the text to a format it can parse.  To do this you need to change the first two `.` to `:`  You can use SUBSTITUTE to do that:

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",":",2),".",":",1)
```

This will turn the string into:

```
23-DEC-19 09:00:17.393922000 AM
```

Which can be parsed.

So your formula will be:

```
=INT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,".",":",2),".",":",1)-SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",":",2),".",":",1)) & " days, "
& HOUR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,".",":",2),".",":",1)-SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",":",2),".",":",1)) & " hours, "
& MINUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,".",":",2),".",":",1)-SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",":",2),".",":",1)) & " minutes and "
& SECOND(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,".",":",2),".",":",1)-SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",":",2),".",":",1)) & " seconds"
```

[image]